# How to setup SSL in SQL Server 2012 with own certificate?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssl

Environment: Windows 7 Professional x64 in a domain, running SQL Server 2012. I have local admin rights, so messing up the system is easy. My SQL Server instances are `SQLEXPRESS` and `MSSQLSERVER`. FQDN should be for example `my-pc.mydomain.local`.

Problem:

I don't know the right way to setup SSL on this SQL Server. **I actually only want to setup SSL with a certificate created of my own.**

Can anybody help me out here? Most of the documentation online only describes the way of going through a CA and have different knowleadge as a prerequirement.

Comment: Have you researched 'creating a self signed certificate'. There should be plenty of tutorials online for this.

Answer (score 2):

[This blog post](http://thedataspecialist.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/using-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-with-sql-server/) details the entire process.

You use IIS manager to create a self signed certificate, then add it through the Certificates MMC for the computer account.

Then give SQL server's service account read permissions on the certificate, and choose the certificate in SQL Server's network configuration in configuration manager.